# Installing PyQt4 with Python 3 - error

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

I followed instructions to download and install sip and pyqt4 here

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1777613

I have PyQt4 via aptitude working for my Python 2.7 installation; to get it to work for Python 3, when i run sudo make, i get the following messsage:

```
    make[1]: Entering directory `/home/usman/programs/PyQt-x11-gpl-4.10/QtCore'
g++ -c -m64 -pipe -fPIC -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -DNDEBUG -DSIP_PROTECTED_IS_PUBLIC -Dprotected=public -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_CORE_LIB -I. -I/home/usman/programs/PyQt-x11-gpl-4.10/qpy/QtCore -I/usr/include/python3.2mu -I/usr/mkspecs/linux-g++ -I/usr/include/qt4/QtCore -I/usr/include/qt4 -o sipQtCorecmodule.o sipQtCorecmodule.cpp
/home/usman/programs/PyQt-x11-gpl-4.10/QtCore/sipQtCorecmodule.cpp:9883:1: error: braces around scalar initialiser for type ‘sipSubClassConvertorDef* {aka _sipSubClassConvertorDef*}’
make[1]: *** [sipQtCorecmodule.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/usman/programs/PyQt-x11-gpl-4.10/QtCore'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Does anyone know the solution? Thanks

Comment: isn't there any python3-pyqt4 in your ubuntu? are you using 11.04?

Comment: Why not using the version on the repositories? python3-pyqt4

Comment: That worked .. wasn't aware of the option. Thanks loads

Comment: Take a look at:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7942887/how-to-configure-pyqt4-for-python-3-in-ubuntu I was stuck and it solved my problem.

Answer (score -1):

You need to do `sudo make`. Once you do it, you should be able to compile the source.

Comment: No, you should never need to be root to compile a program. You only need root for `make install` to install it to a system location, but if you need to be root to compile it then there's something wrong with the build process. The question clearly shows a compile error, and it was kind of resolved 4 years ago.

Comment: @mata No it wasn't resolved. He was just using a pre-compiled version. He never compiled successfully.

Comment: @mata sudo did compile worked for me. Otherwise I got the same error. If you have something better, you're invited to compile yourself.