# No such file or directory: ...build/sip/setup.py

Tags: python, qt

I'm trying to install PyQt on Ubuntu.  The list of obstacles I'm dealing with is far too long to include here.  The obstacle I'm currently trying to get past is this:

```
(myvenv)% cd ~/.virtualenvs/myvenv/build/pyqt
(myvenv)% python ./configure.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./configure.py", line 32, in <module>
    import sipconfig
```

OK, so let's install `sipconfig`...

```
(myvenv)% pip install SIP
Downloading/unpacking SIP
  Downloading sip-4.14.8-snapshot-02bdf6cc32c1.zip (848Kb): 848Kb downloaded
  Running setup.py egg_info for package SIP
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 14, in <module>
    IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/yt/.virtualenvs/myvenv/build/SIP/setup.py'
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 14, in <module>

IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/yt/.virtualenvs/myvenv/build/SIP/setup.py'

----------------------------------------
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /home/yt/.virtualenvs/myvenv/build/SIP
Storing complete log in /home/yt/.pip/pip.log
```

The only recipe I've found so far installing SIP is this

```
python configure.py
make
sudo make install
```

But, on Ubuntu I try to do every installation through `apt-get`, so I'm reluctant to follow the recipe above.

How else can I install SIP?

Answer (score 0):

allready answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7942887/how-to-configure-pyqt4-for-python-3-in-ubuntu)

start all from the beginning and make sure that all dependencies are satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure I understand, but PyQt is in the package repositry, so

```
apt-get install python-qt4
```

And for Python 3:

```
apt-get install python3-pyqt4
```

should install it and the dependencies?

(I would add this as a comment, rather than an answer, but I don't have enough rep to do so..)